# Show $\mid\textrm{tr}(A^tB)\mid\le\sqrt{\textrm{tr}(A^tA)\cdot\textrm{tr}(B^tB)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Show that for all matrices $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ the inequality $$\mid\textrm{tr}(A^tB)\mid\le\sqrt{\textrm{tr}(A^tA)\cdot\textrm{tr}(B^tB)}$$ holds.

It looks similar to Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality, (how) can it be applied in this case?

Comment: Square the LHS, and use the definition of $tr$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. Consider your matrixes as vertors of length $n \times n$ with the standard scalar product on $R^{n \times n}$:

$$tr(A^{T}B) = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}b_{ij} = A \cdot B$$

Comment: Using that I get $\mid AB\mid \le \sqrt{A^2B^2}=\sqrt{(AB)^2}=AB$. Whats the matter with the modulus on the LHS?

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality tells that modulus of a scalar product of vectors is no grater than product of vectors lengths. We see that $tr(A_{T}B)$ is a scalar product of vectors A and B and $\sqrt{tr(A_{T}A})$ is a length of vector A. Thus, your first inequality is exactly the the Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality.